# jsprit how to add a shipment to a specified vehicle

Tags: jsprit

I have a shipment need a specified vehicle to deliver (not because of it has size constraint or tight time window).

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the skill / required skill for this.

Skills are on vehicles and required skills on services, shipments and delivery.

I think that you can try to add a capacity dimension too.

See this exemple : https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-examples/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/examples/MultipleProductsWithLoadConstraintExample.java

But try with the skills first ;).